# Retrieve uploaded files in uploaded sequence yii php

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I am trying to upload image files in directory(/images/users/photos) and display the uploaded images in view. It is working.
Here is my code to upload images files in controller.

```
 public function actionImage() {
    $model = new ImageUpload ( 'user' );

    if (isset ( $_POST ['ImageUpload'] )) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST ['ImageUpload'];
        $model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance ( $model, 'image' );
        if ($model->validate ()) {
            $path = realpath ( dirname ( $model->image ) );
            $imagePath = $path . Yii::app ()->params ['logoUploadPath'] . $model->image;
            $model->image->saveAs ( $imagePath );   
        } 
    } else {
        Yii::app ()->user->setFlash ( 'image-error', "Please select file!" );
    }
    $this->redirect ( 'index', array (
            'model' => $model 
    ) );
}
```

In view i am displaying the uploaded images using following code.

```
 <?php 
            $files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::app()->basePath."/..".Yii::app()->params['logoUploadPath'],array('fileTypes'=>array('gif','png','jpg','jpeg'),'level'=>0));
            foreach ($files as $file)
            {   
                $upload = new ImageUpload();
                $image = basename($file);
                $src = Yii::app()->params['logoUploadPath'].$image;
                ?>
                <div class="img-wraplogo">
                    <?php  echo CHtml::image($src,$image,array("title"=>'Image', 'class'=>'existing-thumbnail-image')); ?>
                </div>  
<?php }}?>
```

Problem is that 
image file are appearing in the alphabetical order in the view. But i want to show them in order of their uploading.

For example: i have uploaded two files, first B.png then A.png, my view is showing A.png first then B.png. but i want to display B.png first then A.png.

Please help me to figure out the above scenario or any hint to achieve this.
I am uploading the images path is **/images/users/photos**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some thing like this and it works!

```
    $files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::app()->basePath."/..".Yii::app()->params['logoUploadPath'],array('fileTypes'=>array('gif','png','jpg','jpeg'),'level'=>0));       
    $results = array();
    foreach ($files as $file){
            $results[] = array('file' => $file, 'time' => filemtime($file));
    }
    uasort($results, function($file1, $file2) {
        if ( $file1['time'] == $file2['time'] )
            return 0;                   
        return $file1['time'] > $file2['time'] ? -1 : 1;
    });
   foreach ($results as $file)
        {   
            $upload = new ImageUpload();
            $image = basename($file);
            $src = Yii::app()->params['logoUploadPath'].$image;
            ?>
            <div class="img-wraplogo">
                <?php  echo CHtml::image($src,$image,array("title"=>'Image', 'class'=>'existing-thumbnail-image')); ?>
            </div>  
   <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the [`CFileHelper`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileHelper#findFiles-detail) method:

```
public static function findFiles($dir,$options=array())
{
    $fileTypes=array();
    $exclude=array();
    $level=-1;
    extract($options);
    $list=self::findFilesRecursive($dir,'',$fileTypes,$exclude,$level);
    sort($list);
    return $list;
}
```

A `sort()` function is used. You do not want this default sort method. However, this method does not accept parameters to modify the sort function.

Therefore, the only way would be to write your own `CustomFileHelper` class which extends from `CFileHelper`, and rewrite your own function that sorts by the date instead.

If you have actually written some code to extend this class, but encounter problems, please post a new question with the code that you have tried.

Alternatively, you can search for a [non-Yii PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20sort%20file%20list%20by%20date).

Answer (score 1):

Solution requires PHP 5.3.

```
$files = CFileHelper::findFiles(Yii::app()->basePath."/..".Yii::app()->params['logoUploadPath'],array('fileTypes'=>array('gif','png','jpg','jpeg'),'level'=>0));

usort($files, function($a, $b) {
      return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
 });
```

Or try this:

```
usort($files, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a)<filemtime($b);'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider storing the files data into your database, that way it will be much easier and faster to retrieve file list, you can also sort and filter with more flexibility.